# How to upload pictures cloudinary?

Tags: node.js, axios, cloudinary

I write code simple code for upload images cloudinary. But somewhere have errors.

```
import axios from 'axios'

const uploadPic = async (media) => {
    try {
        const form = new FormData();
        form.append('file', media);
        form.append('upload_presets', 'social_media');
        form.append('cloud_name', 'tmcotem');
        const res = await axios.post(process.env.CLOUDINARY_URL, form)
        return res.data.url;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
export default uploadPic;
```

`CLOUDINARY_URL` is `CLOUDINARY_URL: "https:api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/tmcotem/image/upload`

But I cant upload. Please help me. i dashboard cloudinary cloud name is tmcotem but top right bar written another cloud name. I try these cloud names. But cant it. when i upload image i get this error:

> Error: Request failed with status code 400
> at createError (createError.js:16:1)
> at settle (settle.js:17:1)
> at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:54:1)

Comment: "*I cant upload*" is not a helpful problem statement. What errors are you seeing? What is the expected behavior, and what *actually* happens? Please familiarize yourself with [ask] and edit your question to conform to the guidance therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no parameter in Cloudinary called `upload_presets` it should be `upload_preset` instead (see the [upload()](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method) parameters for reference.

Also, you won't need to pass the `cloud_name` in your form-data as it's part of the URL you're POSTing to so that line can be removed entirely.

Those two changes should resolve the upload issues.